# Access the camera in SCNView if allowsCameraControl is on?

Tags: macos, scenekit

I'm using an SCNView with *very* basic needs, so I turned on allowsCameraControl. However, I've found that the default is too far from the objects, it needs to zoom in a little. I could do this by setting the camera's FOV's in a little... but how do you access that camera? I cannot find any API that returns it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pointOfView` property (defined in protocol SCNSceneRenderer).

Comment: Thanks Hal, that's exactly what I needed (not entirely obvious in the documentation!). I did...   let cam = pointOfView!.camera
  
  cam!.xFov = cam!.xFov + Double(theEvent.deltaY)
  cam!.yFov = cam!.yFov + Double(theEvent.deltaY)